# MySQL - calculate start and end date of months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `months`:

```
id   name
=============
1    January
2    February
3    March
..   ........
```

I have the year stored in a variable:

```
SET @year = YEAR(CURDATE());
```

I now want 2 new columns: `start_date` and `end_date` - both of these columns will contain the start date and end date of the month based on the `id` and `@year` variable. This will be in the standard MySQL `date` column format. Currently I have this:

```
CONCAT(@year, '-', LPAD(months.id, 2, '0'), '-', '01') AS start_date,
CONCAT(@year, '-', LPAD(months.id, 2, '0'), '-', '31') AS end_date
```

This does work but is there a better/cleaner way? Is there a way to automatically get the actual last day of the month?

Comment: Why do you have a table months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first day of the year using `date()` and strings.  The rest can be done using date functions and operators:

```
select m.*,
       date(concat(year(curdate()), '-01-01')) + interval (id - 1) month as month_start,
       last_day(date(concat(year(curdate()), '-01-01')) + interval (id - 1) month) as month_end
from months m;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=742183d3960e2ff55787a0147e76bc2d) is a small db<>fiddle.